# Who is 'Community'?

Tags: support

I asked the question some time ago, still waiting for clarification. 'Community' seems to be some sort of moderator, peculiar to this site. What powers and uses does it have in comparison to the other mods, who do a good job, often overtly, which is commendable. If this info is already available, perhaps I should be merely pointed in the right direction.

Comment: This should answer most of your questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/236364

Answer (score 2):

"Community" is the user profile attached to automated functions that occur on the site. One of the more visible functions is to own community posts/answers. For example, when a user answers a question and checks the "community wiki" box, she turns her answer over to the community to enhance the wiki nature of her post. Her answer will now show as being owned by "Community." I don't have the reputation yet to follow-up Dom's comment with another link, but [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) provides another nice resource (in addition to [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user/19739#19739), which Dom posted in a comment).